# CfnTopic Python AWS CDK access Topic ARN?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

Given a CfnTopic using the AWS CDK for Python, how does one access the Topic ARN attribute? I'm able to access this property using the higher level `Topic` construct, but not the lower level `CfnTopic` construct.

```py
from aws_cdk.aws_sns import CfnTopic, Topic
from constructs import Construct

class TopicConstruct(Construct):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        topic = CfnTopic(self, id="Topic")  # <- Can't access topic.topic_arn
        topic_construct = Topic(self, id="OtherTopic")
        topic_construct_arn = topic_construct.topic_arn  # <- Can access topic_arn property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ref` property. From the CloudFormation docs:

> When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the topic ARN, for example: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:mystack-mytopic-NZJ5JSMVGFIE.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html

```py
topic_arn = topic.ref
```

FYI - this applies to most (if not all) L1 constructs.

Comment: This did it, thanks a bunch.